# Method called after release() Camera Error?

Tags: java, android

Im Making a App For Turn On/off the led of the phone i can understand what im doing wrong i got this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-42530
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
    at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
    at com.mashi.flashlight.FlashLightCallingService.flashOn(FlashLightCallingService.java:104)
    at com.mashi.flashlight.FlashLightCallingService$1.run(FlashLightCallingService.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**my code is**

```
public class FlashLightCallingService extends Service {

    Boolean hasFlash;
    Boolean isFlashOn=true ;
    Camera camera;
    Camera.Parameters parameters;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        getCamera();
        if (hasFlash)
        {
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while(isFlashOn)
                        {
                            flashOn();
                            //flashOff();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
        }
        else
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        isFlashOn=false;
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    public void getCamera(){

        if (camera==null)
        {
            try {
                camera=Camera.open();
                parameters=camera.getParameters();
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public void flashOn(){
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
    }

    public void flashOff(){
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.stopPreview();

    }


}
```

*Sorry For The language But English Is Not My Language*

Comment: I have done just use ansynctask and is more good or with this code just after i set isFlashOn=false do thread.sleep(250) and something else get the threade inside a if loop if (isFlashOn) i have done this and work exellent for me maybe somebody have the same problem like me

Answer (score 0):

You have a Thread that continues to run after the service is destroyed.  The thread is calling a method on the camera object after the Service has gone through its onDestroy() callback.

At the very least you should make certain that your thread stops when the service is destroyed, and that it can no longer call methods on the Camera after it has been released.

Also, you should never have a reason to do this in an Android app:

```
        System.exit(1);
```

Comment: can you help me how i do that because in my destroy i have " isFlashOn = false " so in this moment the loop it will stop right ?

Comment: If you are accessing a value between two different threads, you will have to synchronize access to that value, or you can have a race condition.  In Java, threads don't see each others' changes immediately.

Comment: so what you recomend to do with any sample code please because im new in java if you can Thanks